# Log in form with admin and user database with SQL server

Tags: vb.net

I don't know what condition to put in `elseif` in the following code block. The `if` and  `else` are running because I want to log an admin and user in the same log in.

```
    If (username.Text & password.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox("insert a username and password")

    ElseIf 
        cmd.CommandText = ("select username, password from tbluser where username = '" & username.Text & "' and password ='" & password.Text & "'")
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If rd.HasRows Then
            MsgBox("Welcome:   " + TextBox1.Text, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
            welcome.Show()
            Me.Hide()

        Else
            MsgBox("Invalid Username and Password")
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox2.Text = ""

     Else
        cmd.CommandText = ("select username, password from tbladmin where username = '" & username.Text & "' and password ='" & password.Text & "'")
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If rd.HasRows Then
            MsgBox("Welcome:   " + TextBox1.Text, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
            welcome.Show()
            Me.Hide()

        Else
            MsgBox("Invalid Username and Password")
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox2.Text = ""
        End If
     End If
```

Comment: You'd be better with one Users table, and a column which says whether they are admin or not. Then you can just run one query. Or you could use a UNION query to select from both tables at once. Then you wouldn't need the ElseIf.

Comment: Oh dear God. So many big security issues, and I only glanced at the code. :( SQL Injection, plain-text password, unmasked password :(

Answer (score 0):

Well,

your solution is not the best, I'd recommend @cj-manalo solution (one table with column for rights)

but anyway...

You can use functions:

```
Public Function Login() as String
    If (username.Text & password.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox("insert a username and password")
        return Nothing
    End If

    cmd.CommandText = ("select username, password from tbluser where username = '" & username.Text & "' and password ='" & password.Text & "'")
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If rd.HasRows Then
        MsgBox("Welcome:   " + TextBox1.Text, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        welcome.Show()
        Me.Hide()
        Return "User"
    End If


    cmd.CommandText = ("select username, password from tbladmin where username = '" & username.Text & "' and password ='" & password.Text & "'")
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If rd.HasRows Then
        MsgBox("Welcome:   " + TextBox1.Text, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        welcome.Show()
        Me.Hide()
        return "Admin"
    End If

    MsgBox("Invalid Username and Password")
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    return Nothing
End Function
```

And call it like

```
Dim rights as String = Nothing
While rights is Nothing 
     rights=Login()
end while
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i got still error . saying  
/*
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized. */

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7q527j726bz5i8/xD.txt?dl=0 . that's my code .

Comment: This is completely unrelated problem. Also, when exactly is this exception thrown? On execute?

Comment: Also I do not see any authentication specified, no login nor Win-auth.